# Run react-native app on android emulator on Windows

Tags: android-studio, react-native, android-emulator, expo

I creae an app with react-native and install android studio, SDK, etc and now want to run app on Android Emulator. I found several posts about this, but none of them couldn't solve this problem

I did these :

```
> set ANDROID_SDK="C:\Users\MyPC\AppData\Local\Android\SDK"
> 
> set PATH="${ANDROID_SDK}/emulator:${PATH}"
```

and try to :

```
react-native run-android
```

occur error :

> Android project not found. Maybe run react-native android first?

Comment: What command did you use to create your `react-native` project?

Comment: @Andrew one time with "react-native init" and another time with "expo init"

Comment: please say how to run in each method

Comment: All the information is provided inside the documentation for [Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/) | for [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) then select **Getting started with native code**

Comment: I read https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/workflow/android-studio-emulator/ completely and follow step by step but can't run